# Django - form validation

Tags: django, django-forms

Suppose I have a class with two fields and both fields are blank, but i want at least one field to be filled.

```
class MyClass(models.Model):
   url1 = models.URLField(blank=True)
   url2 = models.URLField(blank=True)

   def clean(self):
      if not self.url1 and not self.url2:
      raise forms.ValidationError('message here')
      return self.url1
```

I think because I set the two fields to blank=True.
Don't know if using clean() here is true or not and also what to return from it.

Nothing showing in {{form.non_field_errors}}

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use the `clean()` method on a form object. Currently you are trying to make data validation not on a Form object but instead on a database model.

Have a look on https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/validation/ to know more about form validation.

```
from django.db import models
from django import forms

class MyClass(models.Model):
   "Your model"
   url1 = models.URLField(blank=True)
   url2 = models.URLField(blank=True)


class MyClassForm(forms.ModelForm):
    "Your form object"
    def clean(self):
       if not self.cleaned_data['url1'] and not self.cleaned_data['url2']:
           raise forms.ValidationError('message here')
       return self.cleaned_data

    class Meta:
        model = MyClass
```

Comment: I get that the object has no attribute 'cleaned_data'

Comment: Hang on, just noticed now that your are not using a Form object instead you are using a Model object. Let me fix it

Comment: This is perfect solution, The problem is that I was doing form validation on the DB model as you described, and this makes me can't follow with docs. It works now very well. Thanks